# PHP : display "selected value" by default on selection box

Tags: php

I have a `select` box on my form to search shops in cities.  Suppose that they are City 1, city 2, city 3, etc. When I select City 3 and click search, the data is posted and shops are displayed correctly. but the selection box still shows City 1 as the default value.  It makes the user confused!

If I have searched City 3, after reloading the page, the selection box should display City 3 as "Selected value" and not the first value of selection box.

How do I do it? Please help me.

Comment: Could you post the code that you already have?

Comment: Can you post you select box code..??

Answer (score 2):

Just read the value of selected city box and store it in a variable. For eg:-

```
$selectedCity = $_POST['city'];
```

Then use this $selectedCity to check if it was selected when u submitted form check in the select box like this :

```
   <?php if ($selectedCity == 'City1") { ?> "selected=selected" <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option name="" selected></option>
```

for the one you want selected by default, as easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example of how it would be done:

```
<?php
//======================================================== 
// Get the company names
//========================================================
$selectQuery = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `id` FROM " . TABLE_INFO_COMPANY);
while($selectContent = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectQuery)) 
    if($_POST['id' = $selectedContent['id'])
        echo '<option value="', $selectContent['id'], '" selected="selected">', $selectContent['name'], '</option>';
    else if($_POST['id' = $selectedContent['id'])
        echo '<option value="', $selectContent['id'], '">', $selectContent['name'], '</option>';
?>
```

The proper way to have a pre-selected answer in the selection box is to use the **selected="selected"**